# Necessity of SSD in building a new PC

Tags: ssd, compatibility, chassis

Should I buy a PC chassis that does not provide for SSD, if  I need store large amounts of date from voice to text input and also considerable digitally recorded video.   I am NOT a Gamer, but anticipate considerable expansion in the amount of data I/o during the next couple of years. All advice gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not necessary, but the first point to getting better performance out of your system.

Personally, I would save on other components, and never have my System run on a rotating HDD again. For large amounts of data, use an additional HDD. You will really appreciate the responsiveness of your programs.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend it. Yet it does not really matter if your chassis supports it. Most SSD (mine and a few others I've seen) come with a converter.

The biggest reason I wouldn't recommend it is the cost to space ratio. SSD while getting cheaper by the second still cost more than a harddrive. On top of that they do not come in the same sizes that hard drives do. Hard drives come in larger size such as 3 TB where as the max SSD I've seen for a price that is not astronomical is 512 GB.

In conclusion hard drive due to the fact that you do not need the speed provided by the SSD.

Comment: SSD's are more designed as a System drive and not for data storage, so size shouldn't be a deciding factor, unless you're wanting a single-drive setup.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm saying.